# Is it possible to use onload function for a .txt file in Appcelerator?

Tags: javascript, json, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using an example JSON file that is located here: http://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-json-example/

**NOTE:** This url **does not actually have any JSON output**. The example at the address gives the JSON file in a text form.

I know using Appcelerator I can use `onload` to use the JSON file in my JavaScript program, but since this url only gives an *example* of a JSON output file, is there a way to put this into a text file and have `onload` read it in that format? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: A JSON file doesn't do anything by itself, it's just data to be used by another program.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium's [HTTPClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/HTTPClient_and_the_Request_Lifecycle) doesn't care about the content type of the URL you load. It's up to you to handle the data in the unload callback.